# How to connect Google sheet API on AWS EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, google-sheets-api

I am trying to use Google Sheets API to load data into EC2 using Python.
So, I tried this [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python).

But I am stuck [configuring OAuth client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTgUB.png) to get credential.json file. I can't understand what drop-down type I should select.

Hope I was clear. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of applications you want to create, you will have to choose one of the options provided in the dropdown.

[image: dropdown options Sheets API Quickstart]

Since you want to use a Python script, you can use the credentials of type **Desktop** and connect to AWS EC2 from the same application. However, you can always create new ones in the corresponding GCP project to match the application you are working on.

#### Reference

- [Sheets API Authorize Requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#APIKey).

Comment: I selected Desktop app and I get credential.json from quickstart Web page. But when I run the sample python code on EC2, the result showed this message - "Please visit this URL to authorize this application: ~". So, I copied and pasted that url, clicked advanced - go quickstart and got ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error. What is the problem?